# Backgammon/Table game in Qt Creator, C++, how can I track the clicked buttons?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to program Backgammon in Qt Creator using C++,

[image: Backgammon board Screenshot from Ui]

This is what I got until now, I created diverse Qgroupboxes for example `grp_b1`, here I have now 5 Buttons which are the black figures in the upper corner.

```
    grid = new QGridLayout();
    ui->grp_b1->setLayout(grid);

    feld1=new QButtonGroup;

    feld1_buttons[0]=ui->b1;
    feld1_buttons[1]=ui->b2;
    feld1_buttons[2]=ui->b3;
    feld1_buttons[3]=ui->b4;
    feld1_buttons[4]=ui->b5;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            feld1->addButton(feld1_buttons[i],i);
            grid->addWidget(feld1_buttons[i]);
```

I want to ask for help to develop the game logic, I don't know how to track the clicked button.

So when I click on the button I get their id, but how could I know which field is actually being clicked? Because I have many fields, and I can only know which id inside each field is being clicked but not the field.

I would be very thankful for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call method `sender()` in your slot to get a pointer of call object. After that get pointer parent to get widget field.

Example:

```
QObject* obj = sender();
QObject* parent =obj ->parent();
```

And make static cast to widget

Comment: I discovered by trying that: 
`QObject* obj = sender(); `is already the QButtonGroup and not the button itself, so it gives me exactly what i need, wich is the field that was clicked.

`qDebug()<<signal_sender->objectName();`  that gives me the name of the used field.